# JSX/Photoshop: activeDocument.path + string doesn't work

Tags: photoshop, getfiles, jsx

when I execute this piece of JSX from Photoshop works like a charm:

```
var myPath = app.activeDocument.path;
alert (myPath);
var files = myPath.getFiles();
alert(files.length);
```

But this one gives to me an error:

```
var myPath = app.activeDocument.path+"/folder/";
alert (myPath);
var files = myPath.getFiles();
alert(files.length);
```

**Error 24:** myPath.getFiles is not a function...

Any clue on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
var myPath = new Folder(app.activeDocument.path + "/folder");
```

Comment: Hi Mark. It gives to me a new error. The folder already exists and the script must save several images there.

Comment: It says that the folder doesn't exists in the second image save (the piece is part of a "for()" loop that saves several images)

Comment: Can you run JUST the 4 lines that give you the error - after inserting my single line - nothing else. Then start Photoshop afresh and open a document in a folder that has a sub-folder called `folder` in it and execute the script?

Comment: This worked: var myPath = Folder(app.activeDocument.path + "/folder");

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I really appreciate your help.